# Question about making R code more concise through piping

Tags: r, pipe

I have a couple lines of code that I'd like to make more concise using piping so I don't have to define the column name over and over:

```
my_fields <- c(1,2,4) 
timeline_data_1 <- timeline_data[,my_fields]
timeline_data_1 <- timeline_data_1[order(timeline_data_1$avi_date),] #order the field
timeline_data_1$avi_date <- timeline_data_1 $avi_date/30 #divide the field by 30
```

When I try and use piping, I end up getting various errors here. How can I use piping to make this statement more concise?  Here's generally the approach I've tried, with little luck:

```
my_fields <- c(1,2,4) 
timeline_data_1 <- timeline_data[,my_fields]  %>%
    timeline_data_1[order(timeline_data_1$avi_date),] #order the field
    timeline_data_1 $avi_date/30 #divide the field by 30
```

I get an error saying:

```
undefined columns selected
```

Comment: question and answer do not list the libraries required to run the code provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A cleaner way

You can achieve the same result by doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
timeline_data_1 <- timeline_data %>%
  mutate(avi_date = avi_date/30) %>% #divide the field by 30
  arrange(desc(avi_date))) #order the field
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This veers into subjectivity but I always prefer to define/name the result of the pipe last because it flows more naturally with the coding flow. So an alternative could be ```timeline_data %>% do stuff %>% {.} -> timeline_data_1```

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't understand this recent trend of relying/using the `tidyverse` (I guess that's you pipe) syntax everywhere. You are trading some simplicity for additional complexity. For example,by calling additional functions (e.g. `mutate`,`filter`,`arrange`) for which you need to know the usage and syntax.

I would advise you to stick with base R and simply group the commands together in a meaningful way

```
timeline_data_1 <- timeline_data[order(timeline_data$avi_date),c(1,2,4)] 
timeline_data_1$avi_date <- timeline_data_1$avi_date/30
```

Comment: Yes. `dplyr` is great for the split, apply, combine stuff, but I agree with you that for simple operations, less external dependencies are better. This code will work in 5 years. Who knows what will happen to the `dplyr` code by then...